# Can I remove/clear some content from a txt file without retrieving the content first?

Tags: powershell, logging

I could be heading down the complete wrong path for what I want to do here so feel free to suggest better options/solutions.

I have a bunch of PowerShell scripts all with their own log files. Logging is done through a function in a separate functions file. I want the oldest lines in the log to start deleting when the file reaches a certain size so it doesn't get too large.

My problem is with how to remove the oldest lines. I don't like the idea of using "Get-Content", removing the top line and then using "Set-Content" to replace the Log file with the same log minus the top line, then repeating until the log is under the specified max size.

For example:

```
While ((Get-ChildItem $LogFile).Length -gt $MaxLogSize)
{
    $TopLine,$Remainder = Get-Content $LogFile
    Set-Content -Value $Remainder -Path $LogFile
}
```

This obviously isn't very sufficient because it has to put the entire log into a variable and then put it back into the log file.

I'm wondering if PowerShell can simply remove the top line in the log file and repeat that until the file is under the max file size? I know there is the "Clear-Content" cmdlet but as far as I know this just clears the whole file.

Comment: I don't think I've seen this sort of logging behaviour, and would expect a program to create a new logfile when the old one reached a size/age limit. A new logfile every hour/day/week also lets you chose "which" data you keep rather than just "how much". Have you already considered and rejected creating new logs, and removing aged logs with a separate script?

Comment: Why don't you use a log framework like NLog or log4net? Using them from PowerShell is quite easy and both framework provide strategies for dealing with your log files.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler A ring buffer was invented in the 60's. For a practical example about such logging, Windows XP/2003 used one for Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is better known as a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), also called circular or cyclic buffer.

In order to implement such a system, there are a few ways. Are your log entries of fixed length? If they are, calculating the update position is simple enough by multiplying the row size by row number.

Often log rows are of different a length, so you got to read the log file and count line breaks (or what ever you got as record separator) in order to find the position to write into.

The only problem is how to store the log write point. Some implementations store it as the first row of the log, some keep it in memory and initialize it by reading through the log file once and looking for the oldest entry.